# Solve for f(x) given various x, f(x) correspondences

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a real-world problem.

Let $x$ = cost of goods

Let $f(x)$ be profit as a function of $x$.

I want to know the expression/solution for $f(x)$ such that:

$f(250) = 30$

$f(500) = 40$

$f(1000) = 50$

$f(2000) = 70$

$f(5000) = 200$

$f(10,000) = 300$

Is it possible to solve the expression/solution for $f(x)$?  What's the answer?  Show working out, please.

Now, I don't actually want a function that is too complicated or qualified such as a polynomial with too many terms.  So even better as a solution, I want the simplest recognizable common function that would approximate this function.

Comment: Given functional values at a finite number of points, infinitely many functions pass through them.

Comment: That's a good point.  I'm not a mathematically fluent, but intuitively I think what I'm after is the most parsimonious function, the best fit, minimizing deviation, the tightest fit.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) methods that you could use depending on what kind of (and how close) an approximation you want. A quick quintic regression fit [here](https://mycurvefit.com/) yields -

$ f(x) = 13.68244 + 0.08149843\cdot x - 0.00007274243\cdot x^2 + 3.263991e-8\cdot x^3 - 5.354894e-12\cdot x^4 + 2.765461e-16\cdot x^5$

$= (-16)\cdot x^5 + (-12) \cdot x^4 + (-8) \cot x^3 + (-0.00007274243) \cdot x^2 + 0.08149843 \cdot x + (13.68244 - 5.354894 \cdot e)$

If you want an even simpler function, you could use the cubic, $f(x) = (-10) \cdot x^3 + 0.000009219122 \cdot x^2+ 0.004897218 \cdot x + ( 32.39645  - 7.032359 \cdot e) $, but it will be less accurate.